# Is virtual method call thread-safe?

Tags: c++, thread-safety

If several threads share a pointer to the same object, is it safe to call its virtual method? Of course we should assume that the method itself is thread-safe.

```
class Base {
public:
  virtual int test(int arg) = 0;
};

class Derived1: public Base {
public:
  virtual int test(int arg) { return arg * 2; }
};

class Derived2: public Base {
public:
  virtual int test(int arg) { return arg * 3; }
};

//call in threads:
Base* base = (pointer to the same Derived1);
int value = base->test(1);
```

Comment: Were it not, what do you recommend as a work-around? I can't see why it shouldn't be safe - Java does that every day.

Comment: Of course, calling a function pointer while the pointer is changing is a different question altogether (still safe IMO). The same applies to method calls where the object being dereferenced could change. Of course, all of these are perfectly safe in Java :-)

Comment: IOW, I would use it without hesitation, but I don't have the docs to back me up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, that's fine, provided the lifetime of the object `*base` exceeds that of the function call.

Comment: That is the important thing. The dynamic type of an object does not change during its lifetime: from the moment the constructor completed its work to the moment the destructor begins. However during construction *and* destruction it does, which is a surprising behavior (though sane).

Answer (score 1):

Calling virtual functions is normally implemented by looking up a vtable entry in the class.  This vtable doesn't change, so for this implementation, it should be thread safe.

I don't think there is a general guarantee.

Comment: It'd be nice to have an answer from within the language that doesn't depend on implementation details.

Answer (score 1):

I've started this answer about three times, based on "Kerrek SB's comment on a previous answer. As I see it, without reading specs 'til my eyes bleed, I'm uncertain as to what shouldn't be threadsafe of a virtual call - the implementation of the "virtual function selection" (vtable or whatever it may be) should definitely not cause any problem, since it should just be a pointer to the function, which gets called based on the index [or similar] of the function chosen.

I'm sorry, this isn't an answer, but I have a very hard time seeing any scenario, on any processor that I know how it works (x86, 68K, 29k, ARM are ones that I've worked enough with to understand how a virtual function is implemented in assembler) where this would go wrong because of threads - assuming the other code is safe - if in the above example we were to run a second thread that modifies which element `base` points at, you could potentially have some sort of race-condition, where the value of base is pointing at the wrong set of virtual functions, or some such. But that's not the call itself, but the code modifying `base` that is 'not threadsafe'.

Of course, there may some "amateur" compiler around that solves virtual functions in some other way.

Of course, there wouldn't be a sensible workaround, should there be a problem - unless you block other threads for the entire duration of the virtual call - and if you have a class that implements threads by having a virtual function `run(void *args)` as the "this is what to run inside the thread", which is something I've seen a several times, that would pretty much kill that functionality completely!

So, basically, although I'm not able to refer to a spec section that says this is safe, I can't see any solution other than "it has to be".

Comment: Well, as for a standard reference: The standard says which types of actions introduce a data race, and virtual function dispatch isn't one of them.

Answer (score 0):

If the method is threadsafe, then it is fine.

Answer (score 0):

In short:
If not, C++ would not be useable at all for multithreaded programming.

In long:

1. After compiling the programm is constant. So its thread safe.
2. While loading (of modules) the runtime system changes data structures for
   RTTI (dynamic_cast, ...). This is out of your scope but it should be implemented in a thread safe way.
3. After construction the type of your object does not change (you can with very dirty tricks). So all virtual functions of all your objects should not change. So its thread safe.

But you should consider that member of classes which can be seen as an replacment for virtual functions (boost function, loki functor, ...)  may have value semantics and can change while called. In this case it should be documented or better interface for using them should be implemented.

In my opinion you can safely call a virtual method. Even in the case somebody use tries to mimic virtual functions you can expect normal (safe) behavior.